# Stop $mdPanel controller invoking once opened

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-material

In my AngularJS app I'm using `$mdPanel`service to provide a filter panel. The service is called when a user clicks on a button, and when a user selects a filter option, it updates the table, and provides a filter chip (users can see what they have selected) in the header of the table.

**view -table**

```
<md-button data-ng-click="$ctrl.showFilter($event)">
     Filter
</md-button>
```

**view -filter panel**

```
<div>
    <md-list ng-repeat="cat in categories">

    </md-list>
    <div>
        <md-button data-ng-click="closeDialog();">
            Close
        </md-button>
    </div>
</div>
```

**controller**

```
var panelRef;

function showFilter($event) {
    var config = {
        attachTo: angular.element(document.body),
        controller: ['mdPanelRef', '$scope', function(mdPanelRef, $scope) {

          //LOGIC TO FILTER TABLE DATA AND PROVIDE SELECTED FILTER OPTION GOES HERE

        }],
        controllerAs: '$ctrl',
        targetEvent: $event,
        templateUrl: 'app/templates/portfolio/filter-panel.tpl.htm',
        clickOutsideToClose: true,
        escapeToClose: true,
    };

    $mdPanel.open(config)
    .then(
        function(result) {
            panelRef = result;
        },
        function(error){

        }
    );
}
```

The issue is that when the filter panel opens by invoking `showFilter`, and then closes, ad then re-opens again, the service is called again, calling a new instance and resetting all values saved in the `mdPanel` config controller, resetting the filter options, which I don't want.

**Question**

How do I maintain a single instance of the `mdPanel` from the initial open? The user can open and close it as much as they want but all values in controller are saved

Answer (score 0):

You might try keeping storage of your filtered data in your parent controller.

```
(parent controller)
$scope.filterData = {};
```

Then pass the filter data with the `showFilter($event)` function.

```
(view -table)
<md-button data-ng-click="$ctrl.showFilter($event, filterData)">
 Filter
</md-button>
```

Then try using `locals` in config file.

```
(panel controller)
var panelRef;

function showFilter($event, filterData) {
    var config = {
        attachTo: angular.element(document.body),
        controller: ['mdPanelRef', '$scope', 'filterData' function(mdPanelRef, $scope, filterData) {

          //LOGIC TO FILTER TABLE DATA AND PROVIDE SELECTED FILTER OPTION GOES HERE

        }],
        controllerAs: '$ctrl',
        targetEvent: $event,
        templateUrl: 'app/templates/portfolio/filter-panel.tpl.htm',
        clickOutsideToClose: true,
        escapeToClose: true,
        locals: {
            filterData: filterData //add local
        }
    };

    $mdPanel.open(config)
    .then(
        function(result) {
            panelRef = result;
        },
        function(error){

        }
    );
}
```